# Real-time newsfeed for followers - which tools and languages?

Tags: node.js, websocket, real-time, rabbitmq, tornado

I want to implement newsfeed for followers just like Twitter in realtime. But I'm stucked which tools will be the best for my purposes. The solution (complexed solution) should be production-ready. I've tried node.js + socket.io + rabbitmq (node-ampq, rabbitJS), but node frequently crashes... Another solution is Tornado + sockJS-tornadio, but I'm unsure (and know Python not good). Before diving into code, I just need to know which tools are ebst for my purposes and can be 'really' realtime. By 'really' I mean trully fast request-responses. I've tried RabbitMQ + PHP API + Ajax, but it's not 'really' realtime, it uses ajax instead of, for example, websockets.

The data for newsfeed will be like 'John updated its profile', 'Doe uploaded new file' and something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide why nodejs+socket.io+rabbitmq crashes? To make it really realtime, you should use WebSockets, but long polling is an option too, which both are provided by Socket.io

Answer (score 1):

What sort of crashes are they? Node has been fairly stable for some time now, at least for me.

Node is a fine solution, but you introduce some amount of complexity with communication between Node and PHP (which you look to want to solve with RabbitMQ). "Really" realtime can be easily accomplished with socket.io, and since it has multiple fallbacks is ideal for getting a wide audience. Long polling and friends do have their overhead but it isn't too much if the events aren't very frequent.

If it's easier for you to integrate the newsfeed into your PHP program and you are willing to accept the minor overhead I say go for it. Otherwise, I would invest in Node. The platform is still young, but it's matured well, IMO.

Comment: I have existing Yii application and its userbase grows. I'm looking for a solution that can server about 100-200k messages. By 'messages' I mean newsfeed. Eash user follows other users and vice-versa. So this users should able to see ALL updates of each other (of course if they follow) in chronological order. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I just build a realtime web application.Users can drag items and chat in the same page.and I use tornado + jquery pending + redis as a MQ system.It works good, but I am considering to try socket.io to handle realtime requests.

Answer (score 0):

tornado is kickass in terms of performance, and really easy to work with. the only problem is that you need to make sure you have adapters for databases and other blocking-by-nature sources you need to communicate with. It supports websocket of course so you can stream data to users.

If I had to implement this today, the stack I'd use is:

1. Redis for the data and pub/sub on channels.
2. Tornado as the API server.
3. WebSocket for the communication layer wherever possible.

Comment: Hi Dvirk, thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm planning to use Redis as noSQL storage and maybe Tornado + Tornadio

Comment: It has a decent non blocking redis lib, so you're good there.